# Two way communication between two Processes python

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am running two classes on two different processes. I am able to set up one way communication and Initiate my `run` method of Runner class via GUI class.

My requirement is once `run` method finishes its job the GUI class should initiate `terminate` method.

**Note:** I do not want to use multi-threading because my GUI is lagging.

Below is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time


class GUI:
    def __init__(self,conn) -> None:
        self.conn = conn
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("100x100")
        self.start_btn = Button(self.root, text ="Start", command = self.start)
        self.start_btn.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start(self):
        self.conn.send("Start")
        self.start_btn.pack_forget()
        self.prog = ttk.Progressbar(self.root,orient='horizontal',mode='indeterminate',length=280)
        self.prog.pack()
        self.prog.start()

    def terminate(self):
        self.prog.pack_forget()
        terminate_btn = Button(self.root,text="Terminate",command=self.root.destroy)
        terminate_btn.pack()


class Runner:
    def __init__(self,conn) -> None:
        print("Initiating Runner")
        self.conn = conn
        self.main()

    def run(self):
        print("running")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Done")
        return

    def main(self):
        print("in Runner main")
        while 1:
            msg = self.conn.recv()
            if msg == "Start":
                self.run()
                break


class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        gui = Process(target=GUI,args=(parent_conn,))
        runner = Process(target=Runner,args=(child_conn,))
        gui.start()
        runner.start()
        gui.join()
        runner.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

I tried multiple methods to communicate back to GUI but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: Ignoring your code... 2-way communication between processes can be achieved with managed queues

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `GUI.start` method start a daemon thread whose sole purpose is to wait for a `Quit` message sent from the `Runner.run` method upon its completion:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time
from threading import Thread

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, conn) -> None:
        self.conn = conn
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("100x100")
        self.start_btn = Button(self.root, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.start_btn.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start(self):
        def terminator():
            while True:
                msg = self.conn.recv()
                if msg == 'Quit':
                    print('calling self.terminate()')
                    self.terminate()
                    break

        Thread(target=terminator, daemon=True).start()

        self.conn.send("Start")
        self.start_btn.pack_forget()
        self.prog = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate', length=280)
        self.prog.pack()
        self.prog.start()

    def terminate(self):
        self.prog.pack_forget()
        terminate_btn = Button(self.root, text="Terminate", command=self.root.destroy)
        terminate_btn.pack()


class Runner:
    def __init__(self, conn) -> None:
        print("Initiating Runner")
        self.conn = conn
        self.main()

    def run(self):
        print("running")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Done")
        self.conn.send('Quit')

    def main(self):
        print("in Runner main")
        while True:
            msg = self.conn.recv()
            if msg == "Start":
                self.run()
                break


class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        gui = Process(target=GUI, args=(parent_conn,))
        runner = Process(target=Runner, args=(child_conn,))
        gui.start()
        runner.start()
        gui.join()
        runner.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Prints:

```None
Initiating Runner
in Runner main
running
Done
calling self.terminate()
```

Comment: Did this answer your question or have I misunderstood it?